# Custom formatting of cells linked to a checkbox in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a column which is linked to a set of checkboxes.
I have figured out how to use conditional formatting to change the color of the cells in the linked column based on the TRUE/FALSE state of their checkbox, but I would also change the text from "TRUE"/"FALSE" to other words, but I can not figure that out.  I have tried setting a string under "Number" > "Custom" in conditional formatting but it appears to have no effect.  I am *guessing* this is because they aren't numbers, but I can't find any more suitable place.

[image: excel cells]

Comment: Why not use cell link where the `Check Boxes` are placed rather using a different cell, and where you have linked earlier use there a formula with `IF()` condition. And what is the word or string you want to show

Comment: Ah, I thought the boxes were kinda weird, I’ll give that a try

Comment: Sure please go ahead, and let me know!